# Trouble updating 'xfun' R package

Tags: r, installation

I was trying to compile a bookdown file in RStudio but got the following error message

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.37 is already loaded, but >= 0.39 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

So I tried updating `xfun`. It did not work, so I removed it from my package library and tried to reinstall it. I am now getting this message

```
package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘xfun’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\Spencer Gordon\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\xfun\libs\x64\xfun.dll to C:\Users\Spencer Gordon\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\xfun\libs\x64\xfun.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘xfun’
```

It looks like there may have been some issue with uninstalling the previous version and for some reason it's working to complete the new install.

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: You probably just need to restart R in a fresh session because some of the files are still in use by your R client.

Comment: I've tried this a few times and continue to have the same problems :/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. Terminate your R session and if running RStudio close it;
2. Open a terminal or command window;
3. At a command prompt run `R -q -e "install.packages('xfun')"`.

Comment: I tried this and I get the following message Invoke-History: Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.

Comment: @spencergw Either you have another command named R or your installation of R is broken, there is only one command line argument `e`. `ErrorAction` and `ErrorVariable` are not R arguments, see [R-intro, Appendix B.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line).